# Which two substances react spontaneously?

Tags: redox

> Which two substances react spontaneously?
>
> (A) $\ce{Ag}$ and $\ce{Cu}$
>
> (B) $\ce{Ag+}$ and $\ce{Cu}$
>
> (C) $\ce{Ag}$ and $\ce{Cu^2+}$
>
> (D) $\ce{Ag+}$ and $\ce{Cu^2+}$
>
> $\tiny{\text{Taken from 2012 Chem Olympiad}}$

The given answer is B, yet I am unclear as to why. I believe it has something to do with reduction potentials/redox or the gibbs free energy. Can someone please explain?

Comment: Do you have data regarding the reduction potentials of these species and elementary idea about what these values suggest? This can only be solved with known reduction potential data.

Comment: This was from the 2012 chem olympiad and they do not provide a table of reduction potentials (and you obviously can't bring your own :P). So in the absence of that info how would you solve it?

Comment: You then need an idea about their reduction potentials, or equivalently, their relative position in the electrochemical/activity series.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the faint outline of electrochemical series I remember $Cu$ is above $Ag$. The substance which is above is able to displace the substance below from its aqueous solution(obviously lower substance is in ionic form).

Hence $(B)$ is true.

We were made to learn this outline in lower class :

K Na Ca Mg Al Zn Fe Pb H Cu Hg Ag Au Pt

Comment: By displace you mean act as a reducing agent?

Comment: Yep...btw kids are taught in the way of simple displacement reaction. In higher classes, they introduce the electrode potentials and other stuff. Like : $Cu + AgNO_3$ ...